# Misconception about ReLu

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I have already gone through [the post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432300/help-understanding-vanishing-and-exploding-gradients) and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-does-rectilinear-activation-function-solve-the-vanishing-gradient-problem-in?rq=1), but they didn't clear my doubt. Let us say if I have a deep neural network like (having more layers about 50):

[image]

Now, my question is:

If I'm using an activation function as the [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), the gradient will be 1 for all values of x>0 and 0 for for all values of x<0. So, where do the notion of vanishing gradients occur for a ReLU? I thought a ReLu was known for solving the [vanishing gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem).

Answer (score 9):

ReLUs don't suffer from vanishing gradients, but they have their own issues.
The main issue for ReLU is the dead-ReLU phenomenon, i.e. a neuron whose activation becomes zero for all samples due to ReLU. This neuron is irrecoverable, because gradients through it are always zero.

Leaky ReLU and other activation functions were created to deal with this issue.

Comment: Then why Resnet (residual networks) comes into a picture for deep neural networks if we can improve the vanishing gradient with leaky ReLu itself?

Comment: @Bits skip-layer connections have been around for a *very* long time, solving the vanishing gradients problem isn't the only reason.  Sometimes you can get a more compact solution to the problem if you have skip layer connections as well (for instance many problems have linear components, which are most easily implemented by direct connections from input to output layers).   Also engineers like ""belt and braces" solutions to problems, especially when they are relatively cheap to implement.

Comment: @Bits the raison d'etre for ResNets is that, with residual connections, you can implement "residual learning", in the sense that you learn increments to be added to previous layers. These, in practice, should be easier to learn than the actual function. ResNet wasn't created to solve vanishing gradients.

Comment: @Firebug So, can I say that if leaky Relu used as activation function in neural network than vanishing gradient will never occur in such networks no matter how deep neural network is?

Comment: @Bits theroretically, yes. In practice, not quite. There's a limit involved due to floating point precision.